# Сависает Debian насмерть v2

Tags: linux, debian

Все с самого начала. Установленная чистая система дебиан 10.3, ставилось все по дефолту. В конце установке галочки  потавил на 
"Окружение рабочего стола"
"Окружение KDE"
"Сервер для печпти"
"SSH сервер".

Система зависает, тоесть полность умирает, ни на что не реагирует. При нажатии на "Caps Lock" на клавиатуре индикатор не загорается, отключал и подключал клавиатуру во время зависания - не помогает.

Железо
Проц e5-1650
Видео GTX550ti
Оператива 4планки по 4GB

Самое странное то что на другом жестком диске с виндой, работает исправно. Не зависает, не тормозит, не глючит(винда почти чистая). Запускал тесты OCCT на проц + на видео furmark(бублик) = 2 теста вместе отработали 2 часа и небыло проблем. Температуры в пределе нормы. Оперативную память проверил memtest, тоже все 4 планки прошли проверку вместе и по очередно без ошибок. Ставил убунту, то же самое, система зависает и ни на что не реагирует.

При зависание, по ssh можно подключится и работать через кончоль, при чем на том пользователе который уже авторизован( не знаю, может это важно). При подключении по ssh к компьютеру все проходит хорошо, можно работь, на все команды отзывается. Для теста решил создать папку, в папке тектовый документ и в нем текс. При перезагрузки, что папка что файл и что текст были на месте. Тоесть зависает сама оболочка. И еще, про попытке перезагрузить комп через ssh - подключение тут же разрывается, но изменений никаких нет

Куда копать?))

Так же сделал скрин с телефона [В консоле ввел top](https://ibb.co/t2BC4wz)

Есть варианты? Думаю из-за драйвера, стоит по дуфолту nouweau(вроде так). С сайта нвидиа идет 390.112(вродеXD) Но не нашел толком полной инструкции как удалить родной драйвер полностью, что бы хвостов не осталось.

Но так же этот может быть и по другой причине. Буду рад люболму совету

Comment: где-то я этот вопрос видел...)

Comment: Смотри лог иксов (`/var/log/Xorg.0.log`) и `dmesg` после падения — скорей всего там написано, кто именно виноват... нуво, хотя обычно и стабильный, но туповатый драйвер, так что большинство нерелигиозных владельцев nvidia'вских карточек сидят на проприетарном блобе... если нет особых религиозных чувств по отношению к оному, то я бы посоветовал поставить его... он есть в ветке non-free официальных репов практически всех дистрибутивов. 500-я серия сегодня уже устаревающая, так что им нужен не самый свежий — 390-лохматый драйвер, пакет будет называться nvidia-legacy или вроде того...

Comment: @Fat-Zer логи гляну под утро, сейчас на работе. А вот про драйвер, в двух словах. Первое - я удаляю этот ноувеау и потом, после перезагрузки ставлю нвидиа? Просто я читал, там народ что-то делает именно с икс сорг.

Comment: нет, ничего удалять не надо... в дебе прописываешь `non-free` в свой `sources.list`, затем обновляешь репы и ставишь nvidia-legacy-390-что-то там... за какими-то более подробными деталями — в гугл: в подробностях и красках это только ленивый не описывал...  можешь поставить и с сайта, но это не рекомендуется; для этого нужны будут хедеры ядра и компилятор....

Comment: @Fat-Zer если с сайта ставить он жалуется на то что установлен драйвер ноувеау и не может продолжить установку. Его можно установить, но он встанет рядом, и не будет работать. Для его работы нужно его как то ручками включать

Comment: Да не фризит видюха так)

Comment: @Fat-Zer в логах ничего критичного нет. Сделал копии файлов через 5 минут как повисла система. [Xorg.0.log](https://github.com/Guselnikov-Maks/sfml_up/blob/master/Xorg.0.log) и [Xorg.0.log.old](https://github.com/Guselnikov-Maks/sfml_up/blob/master/Xorg.0.log.old). Не знаю, наверное сегодня попробую на другой жесткий систему поставить...

Comment: Да, выхлоп смарта было бы неплохо приложить.

Comment: @Rumata не понял.

Comment: @Максим, а при рестарте иксов по ssh'у они нормально продолжают подымается? в dmesg после зависания тоже ничего предосудительного? Ну и SMART жёсткого, как советовали, тоже стоит глянуть...

Comment: @Flat-Zer все решилось установкой драйвера от nvidia через apt install версии 390хх. Но появилась друга, которая тоже достает))https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1105215/xrandr-не-ставит-нужное-расширение

Answer (score 1):

С кедами не работаю, может там есть порграмка для теста диска. Но не пугайся слова gnome - систему это не сломает.

Поставь дисковую утилиту или загрузись с live-cd или

```
sudo apt install gnome-disk-utility
```

Запусти

```
gnome-disks
```

Найди там тест прозводительности. Если результат такой - то всё хорошо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если выглядит как-то так - то диск на выброс.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Притом hdparm и тесты с dd не покажут аномалий. Надо именно рисовать граффик.

График может быть не таким страшным по началу. Потом начинается проверка файловой системы при каждом запуске, потом пропадают файлы и возвращаются на место после перезапуска. На компьютере можно работать ещё полгода при этом. Я поменял видюху проц и мать и блок питания пока понял что косяк тут.

Также зависания может спровоцировать не системный диск, а какой-то старый шпиндель оставленный под файлы - в этом случае система отвисает минут через 15. Также проблемы были из-за какой-то не очень нужной мелочи, например кард-ридера.

Comment: Да я как то сомневаюсь что битый сектор на жёстком может так оболочку положить. При том что оболочка может в случайном случае. А если бы был битый файл, то при обращении к этому файлу бы ложилась система. Да, и до того как мать поменял, стояла дебиан на этом же диске и проблем небыло.  Думаю если диск битый, то система просто включила и подписала, но не как не умирала наглухо...

Comment: Проверь, да и остальное железо работает нормально под виндой, там не работает только хард

Comment: в логах ничего критичного нет. Сделал копии файлов через 5 минут как повисла система. [Xorg.0.log](https://github.com/Guselnikov-Maks/sfml_up/blob/master/Xorg.0.log) и [Xorg.0.log.old](https://github.com/Guselnikov-Maks/sfml_up/blob/master/Xorg.0.log.old). Не знаю, наверное сегодня попробую на другой жесткий систему поставить...