# xrandr не ставит нужное расширение

Tags: linux, debian, монитор

И снова я со своими проблеммами. Суть дела вот в чем. Debian 10.3 стоял драйвер nouveau и он не выставлял расширение монитора. Точнее, это расширения даже не было в списке. Я его добавлял через xrandr потом добавлял на порт и выставлял нужное расширение. Так как к видеокарте подключен еще телевизор (служит как колонка XD ) Пришлось поставить драйвер от нвидиа. ставил через apt install nvidia-legasy-390xx (вроде тавк), точно знаю что 390хх. При установке он мне выдал сообщение, о том что в данный момент установлен nouveau, но мол типо это не страшно, после перезагрузки все будет гууд. Перезагрузился, скрипт (который выставлял расширение до этого) не сработал. Ну думаю не страшно, открыл терминал, и пишу xrandr --new.. добавил расширение, но когда я вводил 
xrandr --addmode DVI-I-0 и  само расширение взятое из cvt, он выдал такую ошибку

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
```

И еще не большой текст. В гугле нашол мол типо надо моник прописать через xorg.conf. Нашел пример, прописал - стало еще хуже. Стало расширение 9..х5.. Удалил этот файл. Вот терь не знаю куда копать. Еще заметил то что при старом драйвере xrandr выдавал все точно, тоесть 2 двай разьема и 1 ашдимиай, но на нвидиа драйвере выдает 3 дивиай и 2 ашдимиай. Раньше нумерация начиналась с единицы, теперь с ноля. Карта gtx 550ti. Монитор старый, самсунг, квадратный с расширение 1280х1024. Подключен по VGA черед переходник DVI-I. Пробывал разные 3 разных кабеля и 2 разных переходника. Но думаю дело не в них на 99%, ведь со старым драйвером все работало.

Comment: дык, а где текущий вывод xrandr и какой командой пытаешься установить?

Comment: @Flat-Zer первую команду делаю так CVT 1280 1024 60 он мне выдаёт модлайн, копирую эту строку и пишу xrandr --newmode значение из модлайн потом --addmode DVI-I-0 1280х1024_60.00 и в принципе после этой команды в настройках монитора появлялось нужное мне расширение. Но я делал еще одну команду xrandr --output DVI-I-0 --mode 1280x1024 и эта команда ставил мне нужное расширение.

Answer (score 0):

Настрой экраны мышкой. Заходи в параметры. В разделе дисплеи (мониторы) поставь объединить дисплеи или один дисплей. Выбери основной дисплей тамже.

Такое обычно когда стоит "зеркальное отображение", а мониторы разного формата.

Если не читается EDID, то вот эти вшиты в ядро

```
    "edid/800x600.bin",
    "edid/1024x768.bin",
    "edid/1280x1024.bin",
    "edid/1600x1200.bin",
    "edid/1680x1050.bin",
    "edid/1920x1080.bin",
```

Открывай /etc/default/grub

В `/etc/default/grub` исправляешь GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="drm_kms_helper.edid_firmware=VGA-0:edid/1280x1024.bin"
```

потом `update-grub` и перезагрузись

Это должно сработать с новыми драйверами нвидии и с nouveau.

Если телевизором не пользуешься как монитором, то можно его отключить там же параметром

```
video=HDMI-0:d
```

На старой нвидии нужно  добыть или сгенерировать edid.bin и в /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-edid.conf прописать секцию Monitor

```
Section "Monitor"
    Option “CustomEDID” “VGA-0:/etc/X11/edid.bin”
    Option “IgnoreEDID” “false”
    Option “UseEDID” “true”
EndSection
```

Comment: Стоит самсунг как основной, второй расположен с лева от этого (стоит на полу с лево так же и в настройках поставил). И проблема в том, что в настройках нет нужного мне расширения

Comment: Edid монитора читается? Я ещё делал force edid через параметры загрузки. Если найду то отпишусь как

Comment: Тот комп залило кипятком) не копипастнишь теперь

Comment: думаю не читает, поскольку он не отображает ни расширение ни модель монитора

Comment: сделал как вы и указали, добавил строчку (старую закоментировал, но она была пустая). Изменений никаких нет. Но я не делал генерацию edit.bin, так как не понял что это и тем более как это сделать)))

Comment: граб перенастроить не забыл?

Comment: ох уж эта нвидиа, меня както достала - купил новую видюху изза проблем со старыми дровами)

Comment: update-grub делал через sudo

Если была бы возможность, то и я бы купил))) а так, имеем что имеем. И что самое странно, в винде все хорошо, а в linux как то криво

Comment: Еще VGA-0 укажи порт к которому подключен монитор, посмотри в xrandr...

сейчас сижу на 440 драйвере - тут drm_kms_helper работает)

Comment: вот вывод [Xrandr](https://github.com/Guselnikov-Maks/sfml_up/blob/master/xrandr.txt)  Так же хочу упоминуть то, что монитор вга, но подключен к видеокарте через переходник. Пробывал менять и переходники и кабели

Comment: DVI-I-0 указывай там где у меня VGA-0 в примере

Comment: `lsmod | grep kms` что-то показывает?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106322/discussion-between--and-eri).

Comment: \drm_kms_helper        208896  1 nvidia_drm
drm                   495616  4 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm

Comment: прогружается drm_kms_helper, должон примениться. порт правильно указал в GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX?

Comment: да. 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="drm_kms_helper.edid_firmware=DVI-I-0:edid/1280x1024.bin"

Answer (score 0):

Используй `zrandr`, он обычно помогает в таких случаях

Comment: а скажи пожалуйста,  синтаксис команд такой же?  Вечером попробую

Comment: Вроде, там только гуй. Могу ошибаться, надо гуглить

Comment: @WhiteApfer скачал с гит. При попытке прописать sudo ./install.sh выдал 

maks@Debian:~/zrandr/zrandr$ sudo ./install.sh 
lrelease: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/lrelease': No such file or directory
qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake': No such file or directory
make: *** Не заданы цели и не найден make-файл.  Останов.
install: не удалось выполнить stat для 'zrandr': Нет такого файла или каталога

Comment: Вечно у дебиана проблемы. Вот в арче такого бы не было, да и ставилось бы через штатную утилитку установки. Впрочем, вывод ошибки всё вам сообщил.

Comment: думаю, если я исправлю ошибки, то мне это все равно не поможет. Так как zrandr это gui для xrandr. Если  он (xrandr) не справляется, то и через интерфейс врятли это поправит. Хотя мало ли, если не получиьтся что то придумать, буду пробывать так...

Comment: Повторюсь, он помогает в 90% случаев, когда человек не может руками сделать через xrandr и не потому, что не хочет, а потому что этот гуй уже хорошо отточен. У меня с xrandr появлялась черная полоса сбоку на мониторе. Я чего только не вводил, читал доки, спрашивал у опытных людей. Zrandr всё сделал норм в пару нажатий, до сих пор прекрасно работает